# How to create more than one table from one database (ASP.NET MVC)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working with ASP.NET MVC. The plan is to create a Website where you can switch between to tables.

The website works with one table but the problem is that when I switch to the other table I can not see the table.

I use one database for the program and created a second public class for the second table in my Context.cs.

For the first table I used:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ImpEx>()
                .HasIndex(b => b.Ex_Nr)
                .IsUnique();
}
```

But for the second I am not allowed to use a second method of it.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ImpExQ30>()
                .HasIndex(d => d.Ex_Nr)
                .IsUnique();
}
```

The error is that I am not allowed to use a second method because I have one in my DB already

Comment: `But for the second I am not allowed to use a second method of it.` Please show us that attempt.

Comment: And make sure to include all error messages.

Comment: It's a **table** - not a "tabel" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have two OnModelCreating methods in one context.

But you can have two or many more builder statements:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ImpEx>()
            .HasIndex(b => b.Ex_Nr)
            .IsUnique();

        modelBuilder.Entity<ImpExQ30>()
            .HasIndex(d => d.Ex_Nr)
            .IsUnique();

    }
```